# Visual packages in c++ for windows (i know i shouldn't use windows =( )

Tags: c++, visual-studio, graphics

I use visual studio in several of my programming classes for c++, but after extensive searching on line i can't seem to find any decent graphics packages that are compatible with the software. i would hate to need to go out and buy Linux (Gnuplot is amazing i know) and this issue is frustrating. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Some information on your requirements would be helpful.

Comment: Why shouldn't you be using Windows?

Comment: for example - what do you mean by 'graphics packages'. And why shouldnt you use windows, its the worlds most common platform and has great free dev tools

Comment: What are your graphics requirements?

Comment: You can find what you want on Windows, but if you really want Linux you could download a free distribution: http://www.debian.org/distrib/ftplist

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick works on Windows, but I am not sure if that is what you are looking for. http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Graphics can mean a lot of different things. Visual Studio has an addon for business graphics.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1D69CE13-E1E5-4315-825C-F14D33A303E9&displaylang=en

Answer (score 0):

You can use gnuplot windows just as easily - it also has a c++ interface